# Always get the latest version of a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

The Gemfile in ruby is great for grabbing gems and making sure you have the correct version, but what if there is a gem where having the latest version might be what you want?

The consideration here is that I've added Brakeman to my CI server. Its version has been locked by the Gemfile.lock. What I'm wondering is, how do I write:

```
gem 'brakeman', 'latest-version', require: false, group: [:development, :test]
```

To ensure that the CI server does a scan that will always include the latest security issues?

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243293/rubygems-specify-dependency-on-the-latest-version-of-a-gem

Answer (score 0):

You just use the `>` operator:

```
gem 'brakeman', '>0'
```

...and then either (option 1) run `bundle update brakeman` on your CI server, or (option 2) create a symlink to your `Gemfile` using a different name (like `ci_gemfile`), and configure your CI server to use that gemfile instead of the main one, there won't be a matching `ci_gemfile.lock` and so your CI server will download and install new gems each time (and it will get the latest version of `brakeman`).